# Refactor this function to use "return" consistently in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, refactoring

I have a Node.js Lambda Function for which Cognitive Complexity was high. So as Part of reducing this complexity I changed the below code:

```
module.exports.someLambda = (event, context, callback) => {
  var someParam = event.requestContext.authorizer['someParam'];
  if(someParam === undefined) {
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 401,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'You do not have permission.' })
    });
  return;
  } 

  // Rest of the code. It should not execute if someParam is undefined
}
```

To the following.

```
const someParamUndefined = (someParam, callback) => {
  if(someParam === undefined) {
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 401,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'You do not have permission.' })
    });
  } 
}

module.exports.someLambda = (event, context, callback) => {
  var someParam = event.requestContext.authorizer['someParam'];
  someParamUndefined(); 

  // Rest of the code. It should not execute if someParam is undefined
}
```

Cognitive Complexity Reduced. But in the function someParamUndefined() I am getting "Refactor this function to use "return" consistently." In SonarQube Scan.

So in function someParamUndefined() I cannot use a return statement at the end as I am not returning anything again another Sonar Qube error will arise. And I need to return callback only if certain conditions are met.

Rather than `return callback(null, {})` if I use `callback(null, {})` then I believe the execution continues after someParamUndefined() function is invoked even if someParam is undefined. Correct me if I am wrong. But this should not happen if someParam is undefined.

So can somebody help me out in figuring out the following:

1. Avoid Refactor this function to use "return" consistently.
2. Not continue the code execution after someParamUndefined() is invoked if someParam is undefined.
3. Continue the code execution after someParamUndefined() is invoked if someParam is not undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*And I need to return callback only if certain conditions are met.*" but you never use that returned value anyway. Your second code is equivalent to *not* having the `return` at all.

Comment: So If I don't use return then my lambda stops executing as it is invoking callback.

Comment: Neither having a `return` or not having a `return` in `someParamUndefined` affects `someLambda`. A `return` is only valid for *the current function*, which is `someParamUndefined`. And what it does is finish it and provide a value as its result. You don't use the value of `someParamUndefined`, so whether or not you put a `return` in there is irrelevant, right now. When the `if` condition isn't true, then the function just does nothing and implicitly produces `undefined`.

Comment: I have modified my initial code. Basically when we encounter error we invoke the call back and said return. Which stopped the execution.

Comment: Because in the first code the `return` is inside `someLambda`, so it finishes the execution of `someLambda`. When the `return` is in `someParamUndefined` then it finishes the execution of `someParamUndefined`.

Comment: When if condition isn't true lambda continues execution. But if the condition is true, it invokes callback, and there is no return statement. Does that mean lambda carries on it's execution or invoking callback means the end of lambda execution.